# MVC3 Partial View modal dialog called twice

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery-ui

I ran into an interesting problem while adding a jQuery component to my modal dialog. The jQuery ui element (the simple color plugin, found at http://recursive-design.com/projects/jquery-simple-color/) was being rendered twice! Upon investigation, I discovered that the modal dialog (that is a partial view) *itself* is being rendered twice. Here is the relevant code from my main view:

```
// Here is the jQuery:
@section Head
{
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#addUserDialog").dialog({ modal: true, autoOpen: false, buttons: [
            {
                text: "Submit",
                click: function() {
                    $("#addUserForm").submit();
                }
            },
            {
                text: "Cancel",
                click: function() {
                    $(this).dialog("close");
                }
            }]
        });

        $('#addUser').click(function () {
            $("#addUserDialog").dialog("open");
        });
    </script>
}

// And here is the rendering of the partial view:
<div id="addUserDialog" title="Add User" style="display:none">
    @Html.Partial("AddUserView", ViewData["user"])
</div>
```

The partial view modal dialog is here:

```
@model UserModel
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        alert("addUser");
        $.validator.unobtrusive.parse("#addUserForm");
        $(".colorPicker").simpleColor();
    });

    var closeAddUserDialog = function () {
        $("#addUserDialog").dialog("close");
    };
</script>

@using (@Ajax.BeginForm("addUser",
                        "OnCallControl",
                        new AjaxOptions
                        {
                            HttpMethod = "Post",
                            InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
                            UpdateTargetId = "userTable",
                            OnSuccess = "closeAddUserDialog"
                        },
                        new { id = "addUserForm" }))
{
    ... // Other form inputs
    <input class="colorPicker" value="#cc3333" />
}
```

The alert statement is brought up twice on the initial opening of the page. Interesting phenomenon: I have another modal dialog that is in the same format, with a similar alert statement (e.g. `alert("editUser");`), and the two alert statements appear in order twice (addUser, editUser, addUser, editUser).

My suspicion is that my method of incorporating jQuery in both the header and inside the partial view is bad, but I don't know if this is what is causing the jQuery function inside the partial to be executed twice. Does anyone have any ideas as to why this is happening? If my suspicion is correct, how do I rectify this situation?

**Additional Information:**

I am certain that this problem is coming from somewhere in the Index view or the partial dialog views, because the modals are not called from anywhere else on the initial GET request for the view.

When I moved the dialog declaration to the click event function (replacing the `dialog("open")` command, with the `autoOpen: false` option removed), the alert happened only once for that dialog on the initial GET. The duplicate jQuery colorPicker widget is bafflingly still there.

Comment: Here is a thing... everytime JQuery dialog is initialized with .dialog() the DIV that's about to become a dialog box is being ripped out of the DOM and either copied or moved ( don't remember which ) to the bottom of the page to make sure that it's not under any other child DIVs. So let me ask you this... do you have multiple places where you Render your header section ?

Comment: @Shenaniganz nope, just the one.

Comment: where is your renderSection anyway ?

Comment: @Shenaniganz In a master _Layout file, inside the `<head>` tag.

Comment: Can you verify that you don't have a Layout pointer in your partial view ? ...I have a feeling that  $("#addUserDialog").dialog( initialization is being called twice and trying to figuire out why

Comment: @Shenaniganz I updated my question with everything from the partial view, except for the other inputs to the model. There are no pointers to the Layout, just the function that manually closes the dialog.

Comment: Another interesting point: When I moved the dialog declaration to the click event function (replacing the `dialog("open")` command, with `autoOpen: false` removed), the alert happened only once on the page open. Both jQuery colorPicker widgets are still there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was operating with a fundamental misunderstanding about how the `@Html.RenderPartial()` command functioned. I didn't know how to access elements of a partial view from the main view. Instead of instantiating the color picker from the partial view, I am able to successfully initialize the color picker from the Index if it is done *after* the partial view is turned into markup. This ensures that only one color picker is placed in the dialog.

This solution circumvents the problem of partial views running their javascript twice. I am assuming that MVC (in this context) always runs through the partial twice, once on the initial markup, and once more when the dialog is actually created. I wonder if there is a way to instruct Visual Studio *not* to run through the partial view until I tell it to?

Comment: The way to do it is not to pre-load your "dialog-to be" Partial view. You can have an empty div on your master view and then call JQuery $('#divName').load('PartialView Path here') to load your partial view in it on demand, when you actually need to display it.